# Parsing a HoAoHoAoHoAoH in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hash-of-hashes

I am new to Perl and have a little idea about hashes. I have a hash of array of hash of array of hash of array of hash (HoAoHoAoHoAoH) as follows.

```
%my_hash = (
    key00 => 'value00',
    key01 => [
        {  key10 => 'value10',
           key11 => 'value11',
           key12 => [
               {   key20  => 'value20',
                   key21  => 'value21',
                   key22  => [
                       {   key30  => 'value30',
                           key31    => [
                               { color => 'blue',  quantity => 10, boxes => [0,1,3] },
                               { color => 'red',   quantity => 2,  boxes => [2,3]   },
                               { color => 'green', quantity => 5,  boxes => [0]     },
                           ],
                       },
                   ],
               },
           ]
        }
    ]
);
```

What is the easiest way to access the "color", "quantity" and "boxes"? I also need to do arithmetic operations with the "quantity"s, such as 10+2+5 (quantity0+quantity1+quantity2).

Comment: When you start using data structures that are this heavily nested, you should consider using objects instead. Take a look at the official Perl object-oriented programming tutorial, [`perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like an XY problem. What are you trying to solve here?

You can access an element of your data structure like this:

```
print $my_hash{key01}[0]{key12}[0]{key22}[0]{key31}[0]{color},"\n";
```

You can also iterate the bottom elements with:

```
foreach my $something ( @{ $my_hash{key01}[0]{key12}[0]{key22}[0]{key31} } ) {
   print $something->{'color'};
   print $something->{'quantity'}
}
```

But this doesn't look like a real problem - what are you *actually* trying to accomplish? I might guess you're trying to parse XML or similar, in which case there's almost certainly a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, this is a "config" file given to me that I need to parse in order to fetch the elements in the inner-most array.

Comment: Is that the format your config file is in? Because that's a trainwreck, and really you should try and discourage people from doing that sort of nastiness.

Comment: Well unfortunately yes. And it is not even in my hands. :(